# ExpandableListView vertical border on expand

Tags: android

This rainbow is  what I am trying to do, I am really desprate I have no idea how to do it, I even consider to draw it on top....

[image]

Comment: maybe splitting the image in two and add one for the group and one for the child..

Comment: Not so sure about that.... It would look ugly :)

Comment: well, if it has just one child per group i would use the simple ListView instead.

Comment: It is required to expand :/

Comment: so why dont you code the expand option? start implementing it and the community can give you an help. Maybe you can see the source code for the Exapndable list view and check how they implement the expand option.. i think it's only a setVisibilyty GONE/VISIBLE but i'm not sure